# Very new to Blender. Need help with hotkeys

Tags: interface

So I absolutely hated the default blender controls and changed them, but somewhere along the way, I made it so I can't use some features. I can't describe it very well, because I don't know what they're called. My question mainly is what's the hotkey for scroll and what are the things in the red called(or the hotkey to click them)? I've been trying to make it right for an hour and still have no idea how to do it. Is there a tutorial for this? I'm really new. [image]

[image]

Comment: The section you have highlighted in red is called the _Outliner_. It has it's own category in the keymap menu.

Answer (score 1):

Did you first search in this forum for "hotkey"?  There's lots of information that may have already answered your question.

I think you need to set some operations *back* to mouse, so a search for "mouse" (filter) will no longer show them.  If you go to Edit :: Preferences, in the Keymap tab you can scroll down and find a Restore button next to any categories where you made changes. It's like restoring to "factory defaults". I see one to the right of your "3D View" category in your screenshot. I'm not seeing all categories for you in addition to "3D View" and "File Browser", like "Property Editor" where you must have changed some settings. Clear your "mouse" search filter to see more, as they may not be labeled "mouse" even when you think they should be so labelled, like Property Editor :: Set Active == LMB.

[image]

Also look in the View 2D category to reset some mouse ops:

[image]

Comment: Ok, I played around with what you said and I fixed it! :) Also I'm sure someone already must have asked something like this, but I couldn't find it. Thanks!